# How can install a package in python like rpy2 on Windows

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to run R code magic in ipython notebook but was told I　need to get rpy2 package installed. Not sure how to do that, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pain in the A-word. I get it work, but not for every PC. Please follow my process:

1. Set up the global environment variables.

(a). Right click "My Computer", choose "Property"

(b). Choose "Advanced System Settings"

(c). Choose "Environment Variables"

(d). Click "New..." and add the following variables:

Variable Name=R_HOME

Variable Value=~R\R-3.0.1 (This should be the folder of R. No need to go down to "bin" folder.)

Variable Name=R_USER

Variable Value=John Smith (This should be your user name to log in windows os)

Then, double click "PATH" variable to add the R folder location at the end of the sentence (separated by ";")

2. Install RPY2 through pre-compiled binary packages:

Provided by Christoph Gohlke

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Install the binary package after downloading.

3. Copy core R files to the correct directory

rpy2 package will automatically dive into "bin" folder to call R.exe; however, the core R files are located one level below (64-bit: bin\x64 or 32-bit: bin\i386). For example, assuming you wish to use 64-bit R in iPython Notebook, to make RPY2 work properly, you need to make sure that you copy everything , except R.exe and Rscript.exe, to the bin folder.

Then you should be able to load rpy2, call rmagic and enjoy.

Comment: My case might be a bit different since I have R installed with Revolution R Enterprise but I am gonna give it a try. Thanks for you exhaustive response.